# How to calculate probability of event B happen when you see event A?

Tags: probability

I have 1000 events happen.
Within 1000 events, 
  there are 200 events with A signature only
  there are 300 events with B signature only
  there are 50 events with A and B signatures

What is the probability of B shows up when you see A?
What is the probability of A shows up when you see B? Will it be the same as above?

What is the probability of B shows up when you don't see A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use conditional probability. 
\begin{align*}P(A\mid B) &= \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}\\
&= \frac{\text{number of elements of } A\cap B}{\text{number of elements of }B}
\end{align*}

Similarly do for $P(B \mid A)$.

Comment: Please use MathJax instead of images.

Comment: Please learn [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).